# Accessing a variable using namespace and a template class

Tags: c++, namespaces

I can't access the variable **width**.

The A.h file:

```
namespace AN{
    template <typename T> class A{
    public:
        unsigned int width; #The variable
        ...
    }
}
```

The B.cpp file:

```
#include "A.h"
using namespace AN;
namespace BN{
    bool something(){
        unsigned int * w = AN::&width;
    }
}
```

I tried also AN::A::&width but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: `AN::&width` makes no sense. `width` is not a member of `AN`, but of `AN::A<SomeType>`. You need an instance of class `A<SomeType>`, then you can refer to the data member of that instance.

Comment: `width` is a non-static member variable. So you need an instance of `A` in order to access it's variable. `AN::A<int> a; unsigned int* w = &a.width;`

Comment: unsigned int * w = AN::A<unsigned int>::&width; .. I tried it but it is stays that width is undefined..

Comment: if i make static would it work?

Comment: @GiwrgosKostopoulos No, you need a **variable** of type `A`, `AN::A<unsigned int> a; unsigned int * w = &a.width;`. I think really need you need to learn some basic C++ concepts.

Comment: @GiwrgosKostopoulos If you make it static it will work. `unsigned int * w = &AN::A<unsigned int>::width;`

Comment: @GiwrgosKostopoulos static members exist independently of any instance, non-static members need an instance.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot You could well be right, but I think he's going to have to find that out for himself.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with templates. It's about classes and objects. The address of `width` is determined by the object that it's a part of; without an object, there is no width.

However, without an object you can create a pointer-to-member; it's not an ordinary pointer (if it was, it would be called "pointer"). Like this:

```
class A {
public:
    int width;
};

int A::*w = &A::width;
```

You use it to access that variable when you create an object:

```
A a;
a.*w = 3;
A aa;
aa.*w = 4;
```

If you really only want one value of `width` for **every** object of your type, yes, you can make it a `static` member:

```
class A {
public:
    static int width;
};
int A::width;
```

Now you can create a pointer to that member as an ordinary pointer:

```
int* w = &A::width;
```

and you can use `w` as an ordinary pointer:

```
*w = 3;
```